# Try to query from dictionary object

Tags: python, mysql-python, falconframework

I was trying to get query result form mysql.

```
def on_get(self, req, resp):
    try:
        db = MySQLdb.connect(**db_conf.dbConfig)
        #use dictionary cursor
        cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

        q = ("select * from BUDGET")
        cursor.execute(q)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        #init the output object
        output = {'budget': []}
        for row in rows:
            data = {
                "id_budget": row['id_budget'],
                "amount": row['amount'],
                "days": row['days'],
                "user_id": row['user']
            }

            output['budget'].append(data)

        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
        resp.body = json.dumps(output, encoding='utf-8')
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

the output i get:

{"error": "'user'"}

Why? what i׳m doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the the answer.

the row table name was wrong.

```
data = {
                        "id_budget": row['id_budget'],
                        "amount": row['amount'],
                        "days": row['days'],
                        "user_id": **row['USER_user_id']**
                }
```

Thank you.